# Failed to stop job or delete job in dataproc google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

When I am trying to delete `dataproc` cluster in google cloud platform getting below error,

> Failed to stop job b021d29d-acc9-409d-8fca-52363076a63c
>  Cluster not
>   found

could any one help??

Comment: Please share more info, such as the command you issued and the exact error message. The error you posted is not known to us to occur when deleting a cluster

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to delete the cluster via the Dataproc Clusters UI. In that case the problem could be a bug with the UI itself which always sets the cluster region argument to 'global'. If your cluster region is not set to 'global' you'll get the 'Cluster not found' error.

The solution is to use the gcloud api:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters delete NAME [--async] [--region=REGION] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

ref: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/delete